# Can [Element].onXXX be used to create a non-trivial hacking issue?

Tags: javascript, html, security, eventhandler

I have a technology where users can create HTML pages. When they are submitted, I externally check the script libraries (`<script src=...>`)  on the page to ensure they are safe, and that there are no <script> tags with content.

My question is: can an `[Element].onXXX` event be used to load / activate cross site scripting or something equally bad? I tried testing this yesterday and I could only get the [Element].onClick to execute 1 function. Is that enough of a hole for potentially malicious code to slide in? By malicious, I mean phishing, data theft, etc. not a relatively harmless popup alert.

Comment: @Pointy I have updated my question to try to answer your question. Can you let me know if it's still unclear where the attack vector is?

Comment: Well if you allow people to provide `<script>` tags as part of the content, it could in general be extremely difficult to guarantee that the script doesn't do something you don't want it to. Now, exactly what that'd be, I don't know; who gets to see the created pages?

Comment: @Pointy I don't currently allow users to submit script tags, but in theory maybe I could add a checker that content of the script tag matches something that's expected

Comment: Well in your actual question: "I externally check the script libraries" ... sure sounds like you *do* allow scripts as part of the content.

Comment: @Pointy My apologies. I have corrected my question again

Comment: Well you *still* allow external-source `<script>` tags; how will you verify that they're acceptable? There are hundreds and hundreds of common utility scripts out there on various CDNs. I'm not trying to be difficult here; you're asking a security question, and security thinking has to be exhaustively thorough if it's going to be worth the time.

Comment: Any external loading of scripts and any inline scripts that are allowed are a security issue, but it also depends on your content. A simple way to add some security would be to disallow the user to specify external scripts in their markup but to have a repository of scripts that are common _and stored by you_ that they can choose from.

Comment: @Pointy I think he's saying that he checks the `src` against a whitelist.

Comment: @Barmar this is exactly what I am doing

Comment: By `[Element].onXXX` do you mean something like `<span onclick="do something">`. That can indeed execute arbitrary code, and it can execute many statements separated by `;`.

Comment: @Barmar your last comment is my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put arbitrary JavaScript code in `onXXX` attributes. It can contain multiple statements separated by `;`. So you could perform the equivalent of a top-level `<script>` tag with:

```
<body onload="entire contents of script">
...
</body>
```

The script there could create a phishing page, for instance.